# Entity Framework Join without foreign key

Tags: .net, mysql, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have a messages table which has an id of the user that sent it in each row.
But I cannot edit the database, and there are no foreign keys.
Is it possible to join without any relationships?

```
var msgs = (from m in dbContext.messages
           join a in dbContext.users on m.userid equals a.id into sender
           where (m.date > LastReceivedDate)
           orderby m.date
           select new
           {
                Sender = sender.FirstOrDefault(),
                Message = m
           })
```

Thats my code, and it runs, but never returns anything. When I take the join away I get results.

Thanks

Comment: Of course you can join, but we can't tell why the query doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to my comment on [Craig Stuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714/craig-stuntz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267540/entity-framework-join-without-foreign-key/4267702#4267702), you can get the 2nd query eliminated and have it all returned in a single query if you forgo the `.FirstOrDefault()` and can deal with Sender possibly being `null` if the join turns up no users.

```
var msgs = (from m in dbContext.messages

                        join a in dbContext.users on m.userid equals a.id into sender
                        where (m.date > LastReceivedDate)
                        orderby m.date

                        select new
                        {
                            Sender = sender,
                            Message = m
                        })
```

Comment: It is possible to achieve the same result using lambdas?

Comment: Wrong. In this query, `sender` is a collection of users. In OP's query, `sender.FirstOrDefault()` simply returns null if no users are found, but it should return messages.